# Rename command not found when running a script

Tags: bash, scripts, rename

I'm trying to to execute a script, which uses the command `rename`.

When I execute it, I get a message `rename: command not found`. Any ideas?

```
if [[ -z '$3' ]]; then
    shopt -s dotglob
    rename "$EXPRESSION" ./*
else
    rename "$EXPRESSION" "$3"
fi
```

Comment: sounds to me like `rename` isn't an installed function anywhere.  Or it's not configured in your script properly.  As-is, that script doesn't define a functoin called "rename".  Further, `rename` can be a perl package extension for `File::Rename` and provides a 'newer' interface / command line tool for `rename` functions

Comment: Did you try installing it with `sudo apt install rename` before running the script?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just had to install the `rename` package.

```
sudo apt install rename
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, could you [edit] to add how you installed it?

Comment: @wjandrea edited.

Comment: Great. Though it's not a function; it's a file.

Comment: @wjandrea I will remember it for the next time. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: Perl `rename` was installed by default up until, I think 17.04. So earlier posts and guides might assume it was present and not mention this step. On other Linux systems, there is another `rename` program which works differently also.

Comment: And to add to what Zanna said, there's also `ksh` built-in `rename` which IIRC is meant to behave pretty much like `mv`.

Comment: @paweljvn Probably add  the information Zanna mentioned so that people can see it when they read the answer. Comments are subject for deletion and not really meant to provide information that should be in an answer.

Answer (score 6):

My Ubuntu has a man page for `rename(1)` on fresh install, but running `rename` gives a CNF error.

The man page style suggests that the command belongs to GNU Core Utilities, but confusingly it actually is `rename.ul` (Ubuntu Bionic / Disco / Eoan + Debian Buster). This command corresponds to the mysterious `rename(1)` page.

If you install `rename` package, the new man page is `rename(1p)`. It's a Perl script, not coreutils.